# Inconsistent directories in Swift

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have the following code to get a directory and create a path to which I can save a video:

```
func getOutputDirectory() -> String {
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,
                                                                .userDomainMask,
                                                                true)
    return documentDirectory[0]
}

func append(toPath path: String, withPathComponent pathComponent: String) -> String? {
    if var pathURL = URL(string: path) {
        pathURL.appendPathComponent(pathComponent)
        return pathURL.absoluteString
    }
    return nil
}
```

When I want to load a list with recorded videos I call:

```
func getListOfMovies() -> [String] {
    do {
        let dir = getOutputDirectory()
        let files = try FileManager().contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dir)
        var paths: [String] = []
        for file in files {
            paths.append(append(toPath: dir, withPathComponent: file)!)
        }
        return paths
    }
    catch {
            print("Could not load files")
    }
    return []
}
```

The strange thing is that each time I load the list, I get different paths and when I try and play the video it does not show.

Here is an example of the same file with two different paths:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/622EE247-1695-4E40-B261-50A310F45ADB/Documents/18%252520Jul%2525202021%252520at%25252017:28:00.mov

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F28FBA1C-952F-4BD6-BFCA-9C5DEE8C1478/Documents/18%252520Jul%2525202021%252520at%25252017:28:00.mov
```

To play the video I have the following `View`:

```
struct PlayVideo: View {
    var moviePath: URL?
    
    init(filePath: String) {
        moviePath = getURL(path: filePath)
    }
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: moviePath!))
            .frame(height: 400)
    }
}

func getURL(path: String) -> URL? {
    return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
}
```

Following the suggestions below from vadian and change in `getListOfMovies()` to

```
func getListOfMovies() -> [String] {
    do {
        let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectoryURL(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        var names: [String] = []
        for file in files {
            names.append(file.lastPathComponent)
        }
        return names
    }
    catch {
        print("Unexpected error loading files: \(error).")
    }
    return []
}
```

worked finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal and intended. The name of the container changes periodically.  Save always only the filename in the struct and get the actual URL to the `Documents` folder whenever you are going to load the file

But there is a fatal mistake in the code, `URL(string:)` is the wrong API to create an URL from a file system path. You have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`

Nevertheless I recommend to refactor the code to use the URL related API

```
func documentDirectoryURL() -> URL {
    return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
}

func fileURL(for filename: String) -> URL {
    return documentDirectoryURL().appendingPathComponent(filename)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using 


     `func getURL(path: String) -> URL? {
          return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
      }`

Comment: Yes, but in `getListOfMovies()` you are using `append(toPath` which returns an invalid URL. As I said in the answer you should not use the string path API at all because it's pretty error-prone. And  by the way `URL(fileURLWithPath` returns always a non-optional.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do a refactoring. Hope that works!

Comment: It works now, but I needed to change to `let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectoryURL(), includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        var names: [String] = []
        for file in files {
            names.append(file.lastPathComponent)
        }`

When I used atPath it threw an exception about the directory did not exist.